# Socialengine - Split form as wizard kind of view

Tags: forms, socialengine

I have a job posting form which is spanning a complete page I would like to make it as wizard kind of view and then submit.

wizard in the sense - break the form into 2 parts and then submit button in the last form.

Is there any way to achieve this?.

what I have tried - 
- I had created a widget and placed that next to the form but it will act as a separate form.

Support appreciated. Please correct me or if any more clarification needed.

Comment: even I am looking for the solution for this ny 1?